# Spigot 1.11.2 IntelliJ compiler error cannot access PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.PlayerInfoData

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have been having an issue compiling the following line of code on IntelliJ using Maven:

```
PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo packet = new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo();
PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.PlayerInfoData data = packet.new PlayerInfoData(gameprofile, 1, EnumGamemode.NOT_SET, CraftChatMessage.fromString(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[NPC] " + this.gameprofile.getId().toString().substring(0, 8))[0]);
```

I get this error when compiling:

```
cannot access net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.PlayerInfoData
[ERROR] bad class file: C:\Users\nokoa\.m2\repository\org\spigot\spigot\1.11.2\spigot-1.11.2.jar(net/minecraft/server/v1_11_R1/PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo$PlayerInfoData.class)
[ERROR] bad RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations attribute: PlayerInfoData(com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile,int,net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.EnumGamemode,net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.IChatBaseComponent)
```

I tried using Spigot and Paper, also tried changing the compiler from javac to eclipse, but there is no change. I have been stuck with this for over five months, if anyone can please help me.

Comment: suppose the jar is not properly downloaded to local repo. try using deleting the files in `C:\Users\nokoa\.m2\repository\org\spigot\spigot` and doing a maven update.

Comment: This is one of those weird issues that also affects MCP installs.  Try deleting the MC-related artifacts in your .m2 repo (everything under `net/minecraft`, `org/bukkit`, and `org/spigot`) and re-running spigot's buildtools to load the proper dependencies.